# Request to reopen my genuine question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I had posted a question today on Stack Overflow which is actually a genuine and a difficult one, but I don't know for what reason the community couldn't get it and they closed the question even before understanding what I was asking.

Here is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/15669227 (deleted).

Would request you to analyze the question and advise on what best can be done in this regards.

Comment: Did you include your attempt at the code and what you thought it should output?

Comment: You are asking other how to do something without showing any effort or code. That's why it got downvotes and ended up being closed.

Comment: You missed the purpose of Stack Overflow, it's not a place to ask people to write code for you.

Comment: I'd take the view that all questions are fixable, so - in theory at least - if you fix this question it may be re-opened. In practice, it is probably better to ask a new question, since it will need to be substantively different not to be closed. In particular, show some code that you've really attempted, and explain what it does do, and what you wanted/expected. You may find that, in formulating such a Good Question, you'll solve it all by yourself.

Answer (score 12):

I can state with certainty that this question will not be reopened, and will probably be deleted very quickly. You did not [show us what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). We are neither your personal research assistants nor your personal code monkeys.

Since I'm feeling generous, however, I'll give you a hint to a solution that's relatively easy to implement: Newton's method.

Comment: thanks i studied the video but i missed to say that in the post - thats all was my mistake and even before checking with me the community decided to close it ... and since the video gave no hints i didnt know what to study and thats why i came to SO.. but i really thank u for the hint .. now atleast i have some idea on whats happening in that problem :(

Comment: @Sandy - When we ask ["what have you tried?"](http://whathaveyoutried.com), a sufficient answer does *not* consist of "Well, I watched this video...". Show us some **code** that you've written that attempts to find `n`th roots.

Comment: ok ... i am sorry i will take care and add my efforts also from next time

Comment: @J.Steen sure thanks for the advise

Answer (score 5):

Your question is stated very poorly. It looks like you just copy/pasted from a site or Word document. Stating things like, "EDIT - we are not allowed to use the existing known methods like power of (1/2) or sqrt()" makes us think it is homework for starters. Then you write in the beginning, "how to write a function to find the square root, etc" with very poor sentence structure, spelling, grammar, etc.

You didn't put any effort into your question, yet you will probably spend more time on here discussing why your question sucks than the time you spent actually submitting it to SO.

Therefore, I am not surprised it was closed and heavily voted down. I wouldn't be surprised if it gets deleted soon.

Comment: sure, thanks for the advise i will take care